# Combining three views under one view in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a requirement where I already have ready three views , now I need to combine two views under single view as requirement ask me to do that.

Is it technically possible if yes ,how?

Answer (score 0):

You can't techincally have two component documents in one page (hopefully that changes eventually) but you can use a module to render output from a component and then have multiple modules.  Basically the trick is to write the output to a string onf html and then just echo that string. in the module.